# how to select all value from two table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

```
 tableA                   tableB
IdPrice      price             id         tax          IdPrice
----------------------       ------------------------------------
  4          100               1          20              4
------------------------     ------------------ ------------------
  5          150               2          10              6
------------------------     ------------------ ------------------
  6          270            
------------------------
result =
price   id   tax
----   ---   ----
100      1    20
150      2    10
270    null  null
my Query
SELECT   price,id,tax
FROM  tableB INNER JOIN
tableA ON tableA.IdPrice= tableB.IdPrice
but this result 

price   id   tax
----   ---   ----
100      1    20
150      2    10
```

Comment: change `inner join` to `left join`. And please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it is not simply changing inner join to left join . .  you need to switch the table join sequnce also

Comment: Haha ,so change it to `right outer join`. Then it dont need to switch the table join sequnce.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    a.price as price, b.id as id, b.tax as tax
FROM  
    tableA a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tableB b ON a.IdPrice = b.IdPrice
```

Use left outer join you can get all the records from tableA.